# Django Rest Framework, hyperlinking a nested relationship

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I've got two models: **User** and **Ticket**. **Ticket** has one **User**, **User** has many **Tickets**

I've accomplished that when i go to url **/users/1/tickets**, i'm getting the list of user's tickets.

I want to use hyperlinked relations, and here is what i see in my User model representation:

```
"tickets": [
    "http://127.0.0.1:8000/tickets/5/", 
    "http://127.0.0.1:8000/tickets/6/"
]
```

But I want it to be like

```
"tickets": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/users/1/tickets"
```

Is there a way to do that with DRF?

The url:

```
    url(r'^users/(?P<user_pk>\d+)/tickets/$',
    views.TicketsByUserList.as_view(),
    name='myuser-tickets'),
```

The view:

```
class TicketsByUserList(generics.ListAPIView):
    model = Ticket
    serializer_class = TicketSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        user_pk = self.kwargs.get('user_pk', None)
        if user_pk is not None:
            return Ticket.objects.filter(user=user_pk)
        return []
```

User serializer (i tried to play with tickets field definition, changing type, view_name, but with no effect):

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    tickets = serializers.HyperlinkedRelatedField(many=True, view_name='ticket-detail')

    class Meta:
        model = MyUser
        fields = ('id', 'nickname', 'email', 'tickets')
```

Ticket serializer:

```
class TicketSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    user = serializers.HyperlinkedRelatedField(view_name='myuser-detail')
    liked = serializers.Field(source='liked')

    class Meta:
        model = Ticket
        fields = ('id', 'user', 'word', 'transcription', 'translation', 'liked', 'created', 'updated')
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use a [SerializerMethodField](http://django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields.html#serializermethodfield) to customize it.  Something like this:

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    tickets = serializers.SerializerMethodField('get_tickets')

    def get_tickets(self, obj):
        return "http://127.0.0.1:8000/users/%d/tickets" % obj.id

    class Meta:
        model = MyUser
        fields = ('id', 'nickname', 'email', 'tickets')
```

I hard-wired the URL in there for brevity, but you can do a reverse lookup just as well.  This basically just tells it to call the `get_tickets` method instead of the default behavior in the superclass.

Comment: While trying to implement your solution, I realized that I have to somehow pass the request object to the serializer, to pass it to reverse function, to get an absolute url. I solved it by passing a request object from view "dispatch" method to field in my serializer. But I feel that overriding a dispatch method every time I want to have request object in my serializer is not a good idea. What is the best way to get request in serializer?

Comment: There's a way to [provide additional context to your serializer](http://django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers.html#including-extra-context).  The docs demonstrate your exact situation as the example use case.

Comment: In  `get_tickets` method you can get the request object with `request = self.context.get('request')`, then call `reverse` as usual.

Comment: @JoeHolloway What should I do If I have to return an query set objects because its giving me an error of object is not JSON serializable.

Comment: @CrazyGeek not sure if I'm following your question, but in newer versions of DRF, you need to pass many=True when you construct your serializer if you're serializing more than one object.

Answer (score 4):

For the record, here is an example of the full solution based on Joe Holloway's answer:

```
from rest_framework.reverse import reverse

class WorkProjectSerializer(serializers.CustomSerializer):
   issues = drf_serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    def get_issues(self, obj):
        request = self.context.get('request')
        return request.build_absolute_uri(reverse('project-issue-list', kwargs={'project_id': obj.id}))

    class Meta:
        model = WorkProject
        fields = '__all__'
```