# Django,DRF, get another app's view name for a reverse

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-views

I'm trying to create a link for another app in my serializer using the solution provided here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/45850334/12177026

I'm trying to match the view's name but every way I try I get this error:

```
Reverse for 'KnownLocationView' not found. 'KnownLocationView' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
```

serializers:

```py
class MissionSerializer(HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    gdt = ChoiceField(choices=lazy(get_locations, tuple)())
    location = SerializerMethodField(label='Open Location')

    def get_location(self, obj):
        request = self.context.get('request')
        return request.build_absolute_uri(reverse('KnownLocationView', kwargs={'Name': obj.gdt}))

    class Meta:
        model = Mission
        fields = ('MissionName', 'UavLatitude', 'UavLongitude', 'UavElevation', 'Area',
                  'gdt', 'location')
```

KnownLoction/urls.py

```py
from django.urls import path, include
from rest_framework.routers import DefaultRouter

from .views import KnownLocationView

app_name = 'KnownLocation'
router = DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'knownlocations', KnownLocationView)

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include(router.urls)),
]
```

I tried replacing view_name with either of the following:

```
'knownlocations'
'KnownLocation:knownlocations'
'KnownLocation:KnownLocationView'
```

But get the same error

even tried to reorder the installed apps.

api/urls.py:

```py
urlpatterns = [
                  path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
                  path('accounts/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
                  path('', include('landingpage.urls')),  # API Landing Page
                  path('', include('ThreeLocations.urls')),  # Triangulation between two Known GDTs and uav location.
                  path('', include('SecondGDT.urls')),  # Options For Second GDT Positioning.
                  path('', include('KnownLocation.urls', namespace='knownlocations')),
                  # Add Known Location To the map.
              ] + staticfiles_urlpatterns()
```

KnownLocation/views.py

```py
from rest_framework.renderers import AdminRenderer
from rest_framework.viewsets import ModelViewSet

from .models import KnownLocation
from .serializers import KnownLocationSerializer


class KnownLocationView(ModelViewSet):
    """
    List of Known Locations In which we can place one of our ground positions.

    press create to add a new location.

    """
    serializer_class = KnownLocationSerializer
    queryset = KnownLocation.objects.all()

    def get_serializer_context(self):
        data = KnownLocationSerializer(self.queryset, many=True, context={'request': self.request})
        return data

    renderer_classes = [AdminRenderer]
```

Comment: Can you write the code for KnownLocationView?

Comment: sure, it's a very simple view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should try to change how you are calling the reverse.
You can find reference to it below

**Note:** If using namespacing with hyperlinked serializers you'll also need to ensure that any view_name parameters on the serializers correctly reflect the namespace. In the examples above you'd need to include a parameter such as view_name='app_name:user-detail' for serializer fields hyperlinked to the user detail view.

The automatic view_name generation uses a pattern like %(model_name)-detail. Unless your models names actually clash you may be better off not namespacing your Django REST Framework views when using hyperlinked serializers.

Try using this

```
 reverse('KnownLocationView:mission-detail, kwargs={'Name': obj.gdt})
```

Or

```
reverse('mission-detail, kwargs={'Name': obj.gdt})
```